# helm and ff-find-other-file

Tags: helm

When I try to use the function `ff-find-other-file` on a C file, and the header file does not exist, I expect emacs to create a header file at the current location.

Since I started using helm, something else happens:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/helm-other-file
$ cd /tmp/helm-other-file
$ emacs a.c
```

`M-x ff-find-other-file` opens a helm buffer with two entries:

```
/tmp/helm-other-file/.
/tmp/helm-other-file/..
```

I expected that selecting the first would mean to create the buffer at that location: `/tmp/helm-other-file/a.h`.

Instead, the following is created: `/tmp/helm-other-file/a.h/a.h`. That's one (new) directory too deep.

If I select the `..` version, to compensate for "too deep", I get `/tmp/a.h`. That's not deep enough.

If I go up a level with `C-l` after `ff-find-other-file`, then select `helm-other-file/`, I go back to this: `/tmp/helm-other-file/a.h/a.h`.

How can I fix `ff-find-other-file` so that unfound header file is created at the same location as the C file, with helm? I'm aware that helm-projectile might fix this, but I don't want to bring in the whole package only for that function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've helm-mode enabled, the minor mode overwrites Emacs' built-in completing behavior, the thing you want is the default (it comes from `completing-read`'s `DEF` argument) value, you can either `C-RET` (`helm-cr-empty-string`) to apply the default value or `M-n` (`next-history-element`) to insert the default value then `RET`.

You can also blacklist `ff-find-other-file` from helm-mode, next time helm-mode won't be involved in `ff-find-other-file`:

```
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist
             '(ff-find-other-file . nil))
```

Comment: C-RET did the trick, thanks! When does the behavior I'm observing make sense?

Comment: @Gauthier ff-find-other-file's use of read-directory-name is suspicious, it supplies a filename such as a.h as DEFAULT-DIRNAME, though it works fine with vanilla Emacs as it simply returns `a.h`, but with helm-mode, when you select the current directory, read-directory-name returns `$PWD/a.h/`.